# VS Code - Python - "Shell integration failed to activate"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I new to VS Code and trying to run a python script. When I try the button "run python file" nothing happens. The terminal does not even open.

When I open the terminal manually, I see a message:

__
Process ID (PID): 3368

Command line: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe '-noexit' '-command' 'try { . "c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\contrib\terminal\browser\media\shellIntegration.ps1" } catch {}'

Shell integration failed to activate

The following extensions have contributed to this terminal's environment:

- 'Git': Enables the following features: git auth provider

I suppose VS Code it cannot find the powershell.exe, but when i search the settings for "terminal.integrated.shell" there is no option to set a different path.

The powershell itself seems to work.

Comment: To troubleshoot, I suggest starting with disabling VSCode's [terminal shell integration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/shell-integration).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.